# PDO Varying parameters - how do i update parts of a database row

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I just went from mysqli prepared statement to PDO prepared statement because it would make things easier for me supposedly

I am trying to only update etc facebook if facebook is not empty, but currently it will update everything on form submit also empty variables, how do i solve this?

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
    $twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
    $youtube = $_POST['youtube'];

$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" UPDATE login_media "
        . " SET login_media_youtube = :youtube, "
        . " login_media_facebook = :facebook, "
        . " login_media_youtube = :youtube, "
        . " login_media_twitter = :twitter ");

$stmt->bindParam(":facebook", $facebook);
$stmt->bindParam(":twitter", $twitter);
$stmt->bindParam(":youtube", $youtube);
$stmt->execute();

}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form class="multiForm" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="youtube" placeholder="Youtube">
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook">
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I dont feel like making alot of if statements and update/query each one if a condition is met, i think it is possible to make it dynamic, but how?

Comment: You need to add a WHERE clause to your query to limit the update to a single row in that table, but you dont show us anything that would indicate what the index of these rows are

Comment: I think you misunderstood, it only has to update etc facebook if facebook is not empty, but currently it updates everything in the row :) it does not matter which row/where it updates :) this is just for testing purpose. So if i enter Facebook.com/blabla in the facebook input field it should only update facebook in the database and not twitter/youtube i hope you understand

Comment: Then you need a WHERE clause to tell the query it can only update if `login_media_facebook IS NOT NULL` or maybe `login_media_facebook != ''` depending on what the default value of that column is

Comment: This line presented more than once `. " login_media_youtube = :youtube, "`

Comment: if I only type on the facebook input box. you only want to update facebook? and don't update others?

Comment: RiggsFolly okay i will give it a go, thanks
@MasivuyeCokile yes exactly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st  :** simple use `!empty()`

**2nd :** This line presented more than once `. " login_media_youtube = :youtube, "`

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
    $twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
    $youtube = $_POST['youtube'];

    if(!empty($facebook ) || !empty($twitter) || !empty($youtube)){


      if(!empty($youtube )){
        $query_string[]= " login_media_youtube = :youtube ";

      } 
      if(!empty($facebook)){
        $query_string[]= " login_media_facebook = :facebook "

      }
      if(!empty($twitter )){
        $query_string[]= " login_media_twitter = :twitter "

      }


    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" UPDATE login_media SET ".implode(' , ',$query_string));

     if(!empty($facebook)){
         $stmt->bindParam(":facebook", $facebook);
      } 
      if(!empty($twitter)){
        $stmt->bindParam(":twitter", $twitter);
      }
      if(!empty($youtube)){
        $stmt->bindParam(":youtube", $youtube);

      }

      $stmt->execute();

    }
    else {

      echo "nothing to update ";
    }

} 
?>
```

Comment: This should do it

Comment: Great, this code makes alot of sense actually thanks  :)

Comment: Glad it help you :) @Javaish

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
$socialMedias = ['facebook','twitter','youtube'];
$preparedStatment = "UPDATE login_media SET";

foreach($socialMedias as $socialMedia){
   if($_POST[$socialMedia]){
      $preparedStatment .= " login_media_{$socialMedia} = :{$socialMedia}";
   $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($preparedStatment);
   $stmt->bindParam(":$socialMedia",$_POST[$socialMedia]);
 }
}

$stmt->execute();
```

In this way, only the filled fileds will be updated.

Comment: I edited the `$preparedStatement` variable to `"UPDATE login_media SET "` but could you explain what exactly happens here? i am a bit confused as to how this actually works

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yes it did, but i am a bit confused as of how this works.. how does it get the input field data? usualy i will bind the `$_POST` to a variable and pass it in, this question is also related to the fact that every `$_POST` data will be run through a regex check to see if it is etc a valid facebook url

Comment: Wait i do get 1 error when trying to submit 2 or more input fields Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/xch07.wi2/public_html/sandbox/ALDRIG_GLEM/PDO/multi_variables.php on line 55

Comment: **1st :** Missing set keyword  **2nd :**  you can try to update two filed .it will not update

Comment: @JYoThI exactly that was what I was thinking that this will never work for more than one field

Comment: I concatenate the variable with each loop pass. If the variables are defined, we will build our query. At each pass, I thus overwrite the value passed to the method `prepare` and I define the associated paramaeters.